# data is not sent to php from ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

hi
in the code below i want to send the email (with input data by user, in case email address) to a php file but

```
$email = $_POST['email']; <<<<<<<<<<<< this retrieve nothing in the php file
```

js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Form").submit(function() {
             $.ajax({
                 url: "data.php",
                 type: "post",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: { email: $('#email').val()},
                 success: function(data) {
                     if () {
                         //something
                     } else {
                         //something
                     }
                 }
             });
             return false;
         });
    });
</script>
```

any reason for that?

i tested `email="onePrivateEmail"` in php and the validation is correct, so the problem is the email is not sent by js file. Correct?

thanks

form:

```
<form method="post" id="Form" action="">
                        <div>
                            <label for="name">Name</label> 
                            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" /> 
                            <span id="nameInfo">Insira o seu nome</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="email">E-mail</label> 
                            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" /> 
                            <span id="emailInfo">Insira um email válido por favor!</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="myPassword">Password</label> 
                            <input id="myPassword" name="myPassword" type="password" /> 
                            <span id="myPasswordInfo">Insira pelo menos 4 letras e sem espaços</span>
                            <div id="bar" style="width: 234px; height: 20px;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label> 
                            <input id="pass2" name="pass2" type="password" /> 
                            <span id="pass2Info">Confirme a password</span>
                        </div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div>
                            <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Send" />
                        </div>
```

as i said (before deleted)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   alert( $('#email').val() ); 

});
</script>
```

this doesn't show anything in the alert

Comment: can you post the form as well please...and just as a side not. A firefox extension called firebug is a web developers best friend, you can view tons of things, including post variables

Comment: how the edited code is deleted? it is a simple form man, nothing more. and...yes i know the firebug

Comment: "yes i know the firebug" --- so what do you see in firebug? Is `email` successfully sent in the request?

Comment: the firebug show that is sent a post request successful. And the json content is {"validatEmail":false} and must be true

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: have you given any other elements  "  id='email'  "?

Comment: solved, solved, i have an error in the php file. thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your not targeting the right form  you want

```
 $("#customForm").submit(function() { ....
```

given the new information I suspect that either you don't have jquery loaded or you did put anything in the inputs

here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrailm/gat8Y/) showing data in eamil

Comment: you are correct. i have a bug in the php file. It works now. thanks!

Comment: @fel so was jquery not loading ?, and your welcom

Comment: better, a problem (bug) with the logic of returns in functions. The js is correct, yes.

Answer (score 0):

I would assign email to a variable and console.log().  Then assign that variable to the email key/value pair you have above.  Might help track down your problem.  Be sure to check your console and check you are getting the value you expect.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    console.log(email);
    $("#Form").submit(function() {
         $.ajax({
             url: "data.php",
             type: "post",
             dataType: "json",
             data: { email: email},
             success: function(data) {
                 if () {
                     //something
                 } else {
                     //something
                 }
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
});
```

Comment: This is pointless since he already knows about firebug thus can see what actually has been sent.

Comment: i get this: (an empty string)

Comment: @zerkms I don't see this as pointless because you can't make the assumptions you are making.  If the the above answer by mcgrailm is correct he wasn't seeing anything via firebug.  This makes it easier to troubleshoot though  since you will be logging the value to console and you will be able to hover over a variable to see its value in firebug.

Comment: @Fel I think mcgrailm has the right answer above.  Your jQuery selector needs to be corrected to point to the #customForm and not to #Form.  Assuming everything you have pasted here is accurate.

Comment: the name of the forms are correct. It is my mistake when i do the post. Is not the problem. I repeat- is my mistake when i do the copy-paste!

Comment: @Kyle Rogers: if he doesn't see email value in request - obviously he will not see it in console as well.

Comment: @zerkms That isn't correct.  Since he was using the wrong selector he would've seen the value in the console but not the request.  Since the selector was incorrect the ajax never got fired.

Comment: @Kyle Rogers: if request was performed - then ajax was called, obviously.

Comment: @zerkms How would a request be performed if the selector for the form was incorrect?  In this case it wasn't the problem, but if you have a jquery selector that binds to the submit event on a form that doesn't exist obviously the ajax request won't fire for a form that doesn't exist on the page.  obviously.

Comment: @Kyle Rogers: if the request is not performed - then the issue is not in the retrieving/passing the email, but in the ajax, obviously. And again - OP in this case don't need `console.log`